# Auto pause/play code for widget player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to auto pause/play widget player when you click on another media on the same page? Example I am playing a online radio widget on my site and i click on another media to view a video, i don't want to click pause on the online radio all the time. Once you click on a video while the online radio plays the radio would auto pause and whenever you pause or stop the video the radio begin to play automatically. How can i accomplish this please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994386/auto-pause-play-code-for-widget-player is this what you mean?

Comment: @RahulS that links right to this question...

Comment: Sorry link went wrong this is what i mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790506/multiple-audio-html-auto-stop-other-when-current-is-playing-with-javascript