# Javascript click to play music url

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, audio-player

I need a sample code for click to play music I am getting all of my mp3 files from my system folder and I would like to play that pieces of music.

My code like this

```
<a href="mp3folder/mp3name.mp3">mp3name</a>
<a href="mp3folder/mp3name1.mp3">mp3name1</a>
<a href="mp3folder/mp3name2.mp3">mp3name2</a>
<a href="mp3folder/mp3name3.mp3">mp3name3</a>
```

How I should go about this using `JavaScript`?

Comment: [Tried this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826147/javascript-audio-play-on-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `audio` tag to play the audio, and if you want to pause one audio if another audio file is played here is a simple javascript code

check what are the elements playing right now and `pause` the audio which is currently playing.

Read more about `audio` tag from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

```
document.addEventListener('play', function(element){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');

    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len; i++){

        if(audios[i] != element.target){
            audios[i].pause();
        }
    }

}, true);
```

```js
document.addEventListener('play', function(element){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len; i++){
        
        if(audios[i] != element.target){
         // console.log("audio paused");
            audios[i].pause();
        }
    }
  
}, true);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('p1').play()">Play 1</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('p2').play()">Play 2</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('p3').play()">Play 3</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('p4').play()">Play 4</a>
    </div>
    <audio
           id="p1"
           src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/Tyrannosaurus%20Rex%20Roar-SoundBible.com-807702404.mp3">
      Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
    <audio
           id="p2"
           
           src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/Tyrannosaurus%20Rex%20Roar-SoundBible.com-807702404.mp3">
      Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
    <audio
           id="p3"
           
           src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/Tyrannosaurus%20Rex%20Roar-SoundBible.com-807702404.mp3">
      Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
    <audio
           id="p4"
           
           src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/Tyrannosaurus%20Rex%20Roar-SoundBible.com-807702404.mp3">
      Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
    <audio
           id="p5"
           
           src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/Tyrannosaurus%20Rex%20Roar-SoundBible.com-807702404.mp3">
      Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>

  

  </body>
</html>
```

Source: [multiple audio html : auto stop other when current is playing with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790506/multiple-audio-html-auto-stop-other-when-current-is-playing-with-javascript)

Comment: How can I replace audio control to write mp3 name?

Comment: @RamazanAlkan Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @RamazanAlkan my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [embed](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp) tag to play audio files

html

```
<embed src="mp3folder/mp3name.mp3" autostart="false" id="mp3name" enablejavascript="yes">
```

javascript

```
var mp3name = document.getElementById("mp3name");
mp3name.play();
```

Comment: This is not enough for me I should use php for increase this but I can't using php for my project only html and javascript

Comment: php for this? why ?